# .net Remote Debugging with Visual Studio -- "Can't find path."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-debugging

My setup is:

Debugging computer:

- Visual Studio 2008 Professional
- Domain access

Application-running computer:

- MSVSMon.exe
- Workgroup only

Both computers:

- Windows XP pro
- Same **local** username and password
- Access to same workgroup

I log into the same **local** username and password on both computers (username == "debugger"), and point VS 2008 to the remote computer, "Robot," under Project Properties > Use Remote Machine, and instruct VS to debug.  In short, I followed the directions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y5b4b4f%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2010/06/15/vs-remote-debugging-across-workgroups-or-domains.aspx).  A ten second hang ensues then an error:

> Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program '......\prog.exe'.
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.

A few extra notes:

- I tried "run an external program" pointing to the output of the project to no avail.
- I'm not trying to debug an ASP.Net application.
- The project source is on the local computer.

Please let me know if you have any solutions or leads.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the executable and debug symbols accessible to both computers: in a shared or shareable directory.  Make the debugging computer's project "start an external program" being the shared directory from the point of view of the application-running computer.

EDIT

Also, be sure that you are careful that you run the correct build.  Don't run the Debug build remotely if the debug framework isn't installed on the remote machine!

Comment: That does seem to resolve my problem.  I'll mark yours as the answer in two days (when I'm allowed to).